# Scala Shuffle A List Randomly And repeat it

Tags: scala, random, shuffle

I want to shuffle a scala list randomly.

I know i can do this by using `scala.util.Random.shuffle`

But here by calling this i will always get a new set of list. What i really want is that in some cases i want the shuffle to give me the same output always. So how can i achieve that?

Basically what i want to do is to shuffle a list randomly at first and then repeat it in the same order. For the first time i want to generate the list randomly and then based on some parameter repeat the same shuffling.

Answer (score 5):

Use `setSeed()` to seed the generator before shuffling. Then if you want to repeat a shuffle reuse the seed.

For example:

```
scala> util.Random.setSeed(41L)  // some seed chosen for no particular reason

scala> util.Random.shuffle(Seq(1,2,3,4))
res0: Seq[Int] = List(2, 4, 1, 3)
```

That shuffled: 1st -> 3rd, 2nd -> 1st, 3rd -> 4th, 4th -> 2nd

Now we can repeat that same shuffle pattern.

```
scala> util.Random.setSeed(41L)  // same seed

scala> util.Random.shuffle(Seq(2,4,1,3))  // result of previous shuffle
res1: Seq[Int] = List(4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: If i use shuffle first without setting the seed can i know the seed by which the shuffle was done?

Comment: If i keep calling util.Random.shuffle(Seq(1,2,3,4)) im always getting a different set. I need to get the same set every time.

Comment: There is no API for retrieving the seed status after `shuffle()` has been called. To repeat a previous shuffle you have to reset the seed to the same status as it was for the previous shuffle. That means `setSeed()` before the 1st shuffle and then `setSeed()`, using the same seed value, when you want to repeat the 1st shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

Let a be the seed parameter
Let b be the how many time you want to shuffle

There are two ways to kinda of do this

you can use `scala.util.Random.setSeed(a)` where 'a' can be any integer so after you finish your shuffling b times you can set the 'a' seed again and then your shuffling will be in the same order as your parameter 'a'

The other way is to shuffle `List(1,2,3,...a) == 1 to a` b times save that as a nested list or vector and then you can map it to your iterable

```
val arr = List(Bob, Knight, John)
val randomer = (0 to b).map(x => scala.util.Random.shuffle((0 to arr.size))

randomer.map(x => x.map(y => arr(y)))
```

You can use the same randomer for you other list you want to shuffle by mapping it